# How to stop web browser from displaying page snapshot?

Tags: html, security, browser

Modern browsers (Chrome, FF, also mobile versions) display most visited pages as a thumbnails on the "start page":
[image: google empty tab]

The problem is: thumbnails, although small dimensions, can sometimes reveal some sensitive data.

I would like to prevent my website, from being displayed this way.
Is it possible?

It would be great if I could define my own image...

Comment: I can't believe if someone's website homepage reveals sensitive data.

Comment: Not homepage. Page after login. Look at the gmail - if the font was larger I could read email subjects.

Comment: If anyone has any doubt: I just tested it on my tablet (things gets worse on a mobile devices due to much bigger font relative to the screen dimensions)... I can tell how much money I have, just by looking on thumbnail of online banking service!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no.

The image is simply a snapshot of your page taken by your browser at a given moment in time. The app itself has no control over when or if this will happen. The browser will capture whatever was rendered at that time. The only reliable way to avoid potentially sensitive data being captured is to not display said sensitive data in the first place.

Unless your app is potentially being used on a shared machine, i cant really see the problem. The user will only be able to see data they were able to see on the page anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I felt the need to supply an up to date answer to this old question because I ended up on this page through Google.

To hide the Most Visited thumbnails, use the [Hide Most Visited Pages Reloaded](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hide-most-visited-pages-r/dhphmpoekpoecdbjeionimpiceigkeil?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) extension. The nice thing about this extension is that it allows you to show or hide each element of the Home/New Tab page to your taste.